# How does the Naylor Report proposals improve the NHS?

Tags: united-kingdom

### Context

The [Naylor Report](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/607725/Naylor_review.pdf)<sup>[PDF]</sup> seems to have received [purely negative feedback](http://evolvepolitics.com/exposed-theresa-may-supports-outrageous-plan-to-flog-nhs-land-and-buildings-to-private-companies-on-the-cheap/).

> Which in plain English means that if a hospital or NHS Trust doesn’t
>   co-operate with these plans to have their assets sold on the cheap,
>   they won’t be eligible for funds to buy new essential equipment such
>   as beds or monitoring equipment.
>
> In short, May admits supporting a report that recommends forcibly
>   asset-stripping the NHS (assets which our tax money has already paid
>   for), selling those assets at below market prices to wealthy business
>   interests, and then spending our tax money again to cover the
>   inevitable financial losses of this fire sale.

Which, commentators are following the rhetoric that the [Tories will asset strip and privatise the NHS](http://www.independent.co.uk/news/health/nhs-election-2017-jeremy-hunt-conservative-win-health-service-a7722461.html) if elected again.

---

Theresa May has shown her support for the report on the Andrew Marr Show stated in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tx3hrpDCct8).

---

The general summary from the report itself:

> My review set out to develop a new NHS estate strategy, which supports
>   the delivery of  specific Department of Health (DH) targets to release
>   £2bn of assets for reinvestment and  to deliver land for 26,000 new
>   homes. As the Spending Review period has already started, and
>   recognising that changes to the estate can take significant time to be
>   realised, this review has also considered the opportunities presented
>   in the medium term. This work  suggests that the NHS can release £2bn
>   of assets and deliver 26,000 homes and with an  effective programme of
>   interventions in high value propositions in London, this could 
>   significantly increase the property receipts to a figure exceeding
>   £5bn in the longer term.

---

The aims I currently see are:

- Release £2bn in assets for reinvestments (anything NHS?)
- Aim to deliver 26,000 new homes in London and the South East to make a profit of around £3bn *in the longer term*.

### Question

What specifically about the NHS does the Naylor Report propose to improve in regards to the everyday running of the establishment?

Comment: Those aims seem to be an 'improvement' for a certain definition of the word. Specifically if you think the NHS is fat, or that housing in London is more important.

Answer (score 2):

The main tenet that the [Naylor Report](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/607725/Naylor_review.pdf) hopes to improve is efficiency. Basically its conclusions are that a lot of these buildings are sitting around empty and not producing much value even though they sit on prime land, while the NHS has to pay repairs and maintenance fees for a lot of this partially unused property which it could save if it sells it off.

The report suggests getting rid of inefficient buildings will **let the NHS save £500million a year in maintenance** and fund backlogged repairs. These buildings are currently worth about £5 billion so it could raise some money for the government and offset other costs the NHS has.

Other than that there is no other significant improvement the Naylor Report would bring to the everyday running of the NHS.